# How to load the loggin name in another view textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view

Hi I have one view called Visitors Form. In that View i have one field called Employee.

[image: Employee]

In the above menion image i kept Employee field as dropdown. But now i dont want to keep that field as dropdown field. If i login and open this form means it have to load the login person name automatically in the employee field and also i enter  all the data and click the save button means it have to save that id in table aslo.

**My View**

```
  <div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="form-group">
  <span style="color: #f00">*</span>
  @Html.Label("Employee Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
  @Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();
               </div>
              </div>
```

I Wrote code which is mention  above But it is not working. . please any one help to resolve this  issue.

Advance thanks.

Comment: Try adding it as `text` like `@Html.Label("Employee Name", new { @class = "control-label", text=" @Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();" })`

Comment: ok Guru lets i have a try.

Comment: its showing error Guruprasad

Comment: What's the error bdw?

Comment: Wait i will show that error

Comment: [![Error][2]][2]

  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ood4T.jpg   see the  Error Guru Orasad

Comment: text=" @Session["LoginUserName"].ToString(); looks like u r missing @ infront of session

Comment: i added that @ symbol but it showing error again venkata krishna
[![Again Error][2]][2]

  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qgibp.jpg

Comment: Remove that `" "` from begining Or else you can do like this. Add `@{string uname=Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();}` at the beginning and assign that `uname` variable to `text` as `text="@uname"`

Comment: ok Guruprasad i try this way

Comment: Beginning in the sense add it at the _top of the file_

Comment: yes yes i know that im checking wait if i got any issue menas i will post again here

Answer (score 0):

You can try these options:

```
<%= this.Session["LoginUserName"] %>
```

OR

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginUserName"].ToString();
```

OR set your value in a span directly

```
<span>@Session["LoginUserName"].ToString() </span>
```

OR using javascript

View:

```
@Html.Hidden("LoginUserName", Session["LoginUserName"])
```

Javascript:
(use this value to assign to the label you have used in your code through javascript

```
alert($("#LoginUserName").val());
```

Comment: Snmgh if i enter all the details and click the save button means it will save the Login person name id in table ?

Comment: If you want that also than you need to save it in a hidden field similar to above i mentioned for Name, and during save click you need to fetch that value (fetch it with  javascript) and save into the database.

Comment: Name is just to show the user, but in backend you can save the id of the user in table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ....

```
@Html.Label("Employee Name", new { @class = "control-label", @text=@Session["LoginUserName"].ToString()})
```